# How to console.log() html with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How do I write html to a text file using Phonegap? I'm trying to follow the example in the API documentation. The file creating works but I can't get console.log to work.

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log($("h1"));        
    };
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}

<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Write File</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: `console.log()` will not write to a text file, it only outputs info to the javascript console.

Comment: I should have been using WRITER.WRITE() instead of console.log()

Answer (score 0):

Use "document.write" instead. It worked for me.

Comment: Does the file system work differently on new Android OS? It seems to write fine on 2.2 but doesn't write on 4.4.

Comment: I am also new to phonegap so dont have much idea.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

`Log.d("info", "YOUR_TEXT");`